# How to correct the error in range(cells)?

Tags: excel, vba

Writing pretty simple script and occured the following problem, the bot stops running when I put in the code:

```
 .Range(.Cells(n, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

The problem is that when I am making `Range("A1")` there is no error, but when I try to insert some iteration mechanism here, something fails.

First of all, I supposed it was undefined cells, so I went with `With` function.

```
For n = 1 To k

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, n), (Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(52, n)).Copy


        With Worksheets("Sheet2")  


        .Range(.Cells(n, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True


        End With
```

Comment: Get rid of the `.Range`.

Comment: Okay, So when I copy without .Range(.Cells(n,1)) and just use Cells(n,1) it works, but still. Why doesn't it work with range?

Comment: BigBen, Yeah, just got it, maybe you can explain a little, why .Range doesn't work here? Because it works with Range("A1"), but doesn't work with Range(.Cells(n,1))

Comment: Because `.Range(.Cells(n, 1))` is equivalent to `.Range(.Cells(n, 1).Value)`. And that is not what you are looking for. Note that I don't think you need a loop here, you should be able to transpose that entire range in one go.

Comment: When Range has only one argument `Range(arg)`, it expect the name of the range to be given. In your case, it look for the Value of the cell Cells(n,1) and try to get a range named as this value. You can use Cells in Range when you have two arguments `Range(Cells(...), Cells(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the guys above, the answer was simple:

```
For n = 1 To k

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, n), (Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(52, n)).Copy


        With Worksheets("Sheet2")  


        .Cells(n, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True


        End With
```

> Because .Range(.Cells(n, 1)) is equivalent to .Range(.Cells(n, 1).Value). And that is not what you are looking for. Note that I don't think you need a loop here, you should be able to transpose that entire range in one go. – BigBen